# How do you embed an iframe into markdown

Tags: markdown

I would like to implement [Toast UI](https://nhn.github.io/tui.editor/latest/tutorial-example01-editor-basic). However, there is a requirement to be able to embed an iframe into the output.

How do you put an iframe into a markdown script?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

An `<iframe>` is just an HTML tag, and [Markdown supports inline HTML](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html). You should be able to just use it.

(And this is a bit pedantic, but Markdown files aren't "scripts". Markdown is a [markup language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language), not a programming language.)